# Different issue with login or request new password in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

i have problem with login in several Drupal sites. When you fill out name and password and give ok, it will do nothing, no redirect to profile, no errors, just reload page.

It happens cause i was move website from hosting to dedicated server.

I read topics here on stackoverflow, but anyone council is not usable (rename template, login and rename back, comment line in settings.php (cookie), repair session table in database, clear all cache tables..).

Any ideas?

URLS: www.bezvazivot.cz/user , www.ddmorlova.cz/user , www.satelitni-systemy.cz/user

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the `users` table...there should be a record in there for the anonymous user, with a `uid` of `0` and all other columns `NULL`. If there isn't, create it.

This often happens when moving Drupal 6 depending on what method you use to do it. Fortunately the problem's gone in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

It has lots of dependency right. Need to  install https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip. And Geoip have other dependencies like enable CURL asking to install libraries using composer.